# Quanteda text models: Is it possible to calculate AUC and plot ROC curves for svm and naive Bayes?

Tags: r, svm, naivebayes, quanteda

I am using `svm` and `Naive Bayes` algorithms from `quanteda text models` package. Is it possible to calculate `AUC` and plot `ROC curves`? I would be grateful if you suggest any example tutorial.

Comment: Not as part of the **quanteda.textmodels** package, at least not as of November 2020. We're working on extending this functionality, but for now, you would need to run the different models and compute this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used something like this and it worked. I am grateful for Ken Benoit's response in the comments.

```
nb_quanteda.prob <- predict(tmod_nb,type="probability",  newdata = dfmat_unknown_matched)  
pred_nb_qaunteda <- prediction(as.numeric(nb_quanteda.prob[,-1]), Truth)  
perf_nb_qaunteda <- performance(pred_nb_qaunteda,"tpr","fpr")  
plot( perf_nb_qaunteda, col="darkblue", main="Roc nb")
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer - nothing wrong with that (on the contrary, it is encouraged).